# Show mysql database data from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables. one `advt` and second `category`. I need to show data from table category where `cat_id` comes from `advt`. I am unable to show categories.

My problem is how will I show category, subcategory and subcat names instead of `cat_id`. I am able to show `cat_id` but failed to show category names from `category` table where name is as `product`

table- advt:

[image]

table - category:

[image]

My php code is as below:

```
<?php 
include('include/config.php');


if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                                 a.ad_id, 
                                 a.cus_id,
                                 a.ad_name,
                                 a.category,
                                 a.subcategory,
                                 a.subcat
                                 FROM `advt` a 
                                 INNER JOIN `category` b
                                 ON a.category = b.cat_id AND a.subcategory = b.cat_id AND a.subcat = b.cat_id GROUP BY a.ad_id
                                 ")){ 


       $stmt->execute(); 
       $stmt->store_result(); 
       $stmt->bind_result($ad_id, $cus_id, $ad_name, $category, $subcategory, $subcat);   

       while($stmt->fetch()){ 
       ?>

        <tr class="example">
            <td><a href="details1/<?php echo $cus_id;?>/<?php echo $ad_id;?>"><?php echo  "<img src=ad/data/img/$cus_id/$ad_id/$img_name  width='180' height='120'><br>";?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $ad_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cus_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ad_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $subcategory; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $subcat; ?></td>
         </tr>

        <?php
       } 
       $stmt->close();
       } 

?>
```

Comment: You need to have check your join condition. You are checking `cat_id` against `category,subcat,subcategory` i.e it will return only the tables which have all this 3 values same and it's present in category table as well. Is that what you want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your category, subcategory and subcat all are references to the category table then to get the name of the category can be get by using below query:

```
SELECT 
    a.ad_id, 
    a.cus_id,
    a.ad_name,
    b.product as category,
    c.product as subcategory,
    d.product as subcat
FROM `advt` a 
INNER JOIN `category` b
ON a.category = b.cat_id 
INNER JOIN `category` c
ON a.subcategory = c.cat_id 
INNER JOIN `category` d
ON a.subcat = d.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the category name then  use the below query.

`JOIN` both the tables on `cat_id` then add product to the `SELECT` part and remove the `GROUP BY`(we assume that category table won't have duplicate `cat_id`).

```
SELECT a.ad_id, 
       a.cus_id,
       a.ad_name,
       a.category,
       a.subcategory,
       a.subcat,
       b.product
FROM `advt` a 
INNER JOIN `category` b ON a.category = b.cat_id
```